# Cocos2d-x::CCLabelTTF not add to layer

Tags: windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want add Label on CCLayerColor, but I did not get...

```
 // on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool SplashScreen::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if ( !CCLayerColor::initWithColor(Colors::GetMainAccentColor4B()) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    auto visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    auto origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

    auto label1 = CCLabelTTF::create("Hello World", "Helvetica", 12,
        CCSizeMake(245, 32), kCCTextAlignmentCenter);
    this->addChild(label1, 1);

    return true;
}
```

Colors::GetMainAccentColor4B() - works fine - it's my class, that give me colors

[Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21386287/screen.png)

Comment: try setting the position of the label after your `addChild` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
auto label = LabelTTF::create("Hello World", "Helvetica", 100, Size(245, 32), TextHAlignment::CENTER);
label->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.width * 0.5, visibleSize.height * 0.5));
this->addChild(label);
```

It should draws a label on center's screen. Don't use deprecated method or class like CCLabelTTF in cocos2d-x 3.0.